# add expr within awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to increment record number variable (NR) within awk script like below but getting syntax errors.

```
awk '{print "dm" `expr $NR + 225` "," $0}'  test
```

where test is a text file with numerous records.

Appreciate if someone can help me with the correct syntax !

Comment: But awk can do addition. What's wrong with `awk '{print "dm" NR + 225 "," $0}' test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need to do in this way. how about:

```
awk '{print "dm" NR+255","$0}'  test
```

also in your codes, the `$NR` was wrong.

well if answer your question straightly, your awk line should be written like:

```
awk '{"expr "NR" + 225"|getline n; print "dm" n ","$0}' test
```

Comment: You don't need the interstitial commas. They will just insert space OP doesn't necessarily want.

Comment: Kent, that worked perfectly.. it was much simpler and elegant than the way i was doing !

Comment: @kojiro oh, yes, I didn't notice that... I will try to fix it. thx